# Facebook Login android.View.InflateException error

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to create an app with a Facebook login for the first time and I have followed all the steps in the guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/ When I try and run the app I get these errors in the LogCat:

```
07-15 20:32:49.081: D/ActivityThread(18598): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
07-15 20:32:49.091: D/ActivityThread(18598): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
07-15 20:32:49.091: D/ActivityThread(18598): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
07-15 20:32:49.551: D/AndroidRuntime(18598): Shutting down VM
07-15 20:32:49.551: W/dalvikvm(18598): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b1c378)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alexlamond.fblogin/com.alexlamond.fblogin.MainActivity}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at com.alexlamond.fblogin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    ... 11 more
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.alexlamond.fblogin.SelectionFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
07-15 20:32:49.641: E/AndroidRuntime(18598):    ... 21 more
```

The code I have in my main activity Java file and xml layout file are the same as Facebook said to enter.

MainActivity.Java:

```
package com.alexlamond.fblogin;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int SPLASH = 0;
    private static final int SETTINGS = 2;
    private static final int SELECTION = 1;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SETTINGS +1;
    private MenuItem settings;

    private boolean isResumed = false;;


    private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);
        fragments[SETTINGS] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.userSettingsFragment);
        fragments[SPLASH] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
        fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            if (i == fragmentIndex) {
                transaction.show(fragments[i]);
            } else {
                transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
            }
        }
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isResumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isResumed = false;

    }

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    // Only make changes if the activity is visible
    if (isResumed) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // Get the number of entries in the back stack
        int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        // Clear the back stack
        for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            // If the session state is open:
            // Show the authenticated fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            // If the session state is closed:
            // Show the login fragment
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // if the session is already open,
        // try to show the selection fragment
        showFragment(SELECTION, false);
    } else {
        // otherwise present the splash screen
        // and ask the person to login.
        showFragment(SPLASH, false);
    }
}

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
    new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, 
            SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // only add the menu when the selection fragment is showing
    if (fragments[SELECTION].isVisible()) {
        if (menu.size() == 0) {
            settings = menu.add(R.string.settings);
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        menu.clear();
        settings = null;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.equals(settings)) {
        showFragment(SETTINGS, true);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

and my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.alexlamond.fblogin.SelectionFragment"
          android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.alexlamond.fblogin.SplashFragment"
          android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.alexlamond.fblogin.UserSettingsFragment"
          android:id="@+id/userSettingsFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run it via an emulator I get this result in the console:

```
[2013-07-15 20:51:04 - FacebookLogin] Starting activity com.alexlamond.fblogin.MainActivity on device emulator-5554 
[2013-07-15 20:51:04 - FacebookLogin] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.alexlamond.fblogin/.MainActivity } 
[2013-07-15 20:51:05 - FacebookLogin] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: The `ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front ` means that you haven't made any changes to the code, and thus it is just bring the app to the front. You have to make a change to the code, save, then relaunch to get rid of that error, even it it's just adding a space to the code.

Comment: Or simply clean and build the project again before running on the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**com.alexlamond.fblogin.SelectionFragment** is not a **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.alexlamond.fblogin.SelectionFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

check if the Fragment that the SelectionFragment is extending from is from the support library (android.support.v4.app).